# Mimic "returning" in an oracle 12c updatable view

Tags: oracle, view

We would like to use updatable views in some cases where information is split across several tables for allowing the use of foreign key constraints. This works well utilizing "instead of triggers" (KEY PRESERVED cannot be used as the keys may come from different tables depending on the constellation).

We would like to use these updatable views like normal tables but unfortunately "returning" cannot be used on DML statements.

Is anyone aware of a way to use or mimic "returning" on inserts and updates (Essential in our case as it's not only about getting generated identity values, also timestamps et cetera)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the `VIEW`, usage of a Transactional API (`XAPI`) (instead of DML on the `VIEW`) may be warranted.  Also, google `SmartDB`

Comment: It is ment to be used in pl/sql code. Sorry, that I forgot to mention